# use an href to click a checkbox to fire an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that looks like this:

```
$('#clearSelections').click(function(e) {
    $("#isAcheckbox").removeAttr("checked");
    redrawTableofListings();
});     


<a href="#" id="clearSelections">clear selections</a>

<input type="checkbox" id="isAcheckbox" checked>

// when the user clicks on the checkbox, doSomeThing happens.
```

basically, when the user clicks on the href, i want to use jquery to make the href handle the checkbox the same way as though the user just put a check in the checkbox.

Does this make sense? When I use "removeAttr" it just removes the checkbox, and doesen't redraw the form.

Thanks in advance! and be safe with fireworks this weekend!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you always want to *deselect* the checkbox when the link is clicked (at least this is what I infer by the text *clear selections*). Then this will do it:

```
$('#clearSelections').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    $("#isAcheckbox").prop("checked", false);
    redrawTableofListings();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/hRRXU/)

Comment: Any reason to use e.preventDefaults() rather than simply returning false? I ask because I have not used preventDefaults before

Comment: @jdc0589: `return false` also prevents the event from bubbling up. Personally I think `preventDefault()` more descriptive and as jQuery unifies the interface, you don't have to worry about IE. [This article might be worth reading](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) and I bet there are some `preventDefault vs return false` questions here on SO as well.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. I guess it also makes you less prone to forget to return false if your function has multiple return points. That has definitely bitten me before.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#isAcheckbox").trigger('click');
```